# How to print bootstrap drop down on console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap$ drop-down with input field i am trying to print or alert the selected dropdown but not getting success

**Code snippet**

```js
$("#gstCodeDropdown").on("click", function(e) {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="gstCodeInput">GST Code</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="gstCodeInput">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="gstCodeDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here i am doing the code fine but its not giving the desire output as i want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the text content instead of doing `val`. This is because `div` does not have value attribute.

This example shows how to get the text of the clicked anchor link and assign it to the input. You can get any other attribute from the anchor tag depending on requirement

```js
$("#gstCodeDropdown").on("click", '.dropdown-item', function(e) {
  alert($(this).text().trim())
  $('#gstCodeInput').val(($(this).text().trim()));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="gstCodeInput">GST Code</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="gstCodeInput">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="gstCodeDropdown" data-val=''>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on putting alert it says [object object]

Comment: @viveksingh what you want to alert?

Comment: selected dropdown

Comment: @viveksingh not to confuse  anchor link with select drop down. Have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. You are trying to get value property of a div.

```js
/* $("#gstCodeDropdown").on("click", function(e) {
  alert($(this).val());
}); */

function getCode(obj) {
  alert(obj.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="gstCodeInput">GST Code</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="gstCodeInput">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="gstCodeDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="getCode(this);">gst Code 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="getCode(this);">gst Code 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="getCode(this);">gst Code 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want which drop-down is clicked or changed..it is here only alert 1,2,3 please check

Comment: See the `onClick` event. 1 is for 1st dropdown, 2 is for sencond and so on. On basis of that you can perform your operations.

Comment: here you are giving onclick event to each dropdown..but in my real code i ahe aal dropdowns from back-end as json..so can't give tem event each time i have to fully change my code then

Comment: can't we do this without onclick..i mean not to put onclick  at `<a></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
   $(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
        console.log($(this)[0].text)
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="gstCodeInput">GST Code</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="gstCodeInput">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="gstCodeDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">gst Code 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```